# How does Firestore name the keys in a document which is set from a POJO?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to understand how Firestore names the key for each value in a document when we set it from a custom Java object. Intuitively I thought it must be from the name of the field in the Java class, but this is not the case.

Instead it seems to be from the getter method name. Is that correct?

```
String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();

Note note = new Note(title, description);

noteRef.set(note)
```

Comment: Yeah its from the getter method, once i had to ignore a field and i added ignore annotation in the field and it didn't work. Then added in getter and it worked. So yes it will from getter method name.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore follows the Java Bean property naming convention for mapping between the Java object and the fields in the document.

*Note: this is the same logic that is used by the Firebase Realtime Database. While you're not using that, knowing this may make it easier to find similar examples.*

Here are some examples of how specific method names map to property names (and this field names):

```
public String getName(); // getter for property "name"
public void setName(String name); // setter for property "name"

public String getUserName(); // getter for property "userName"
public void setUserName(String name); // setter for property "userName"

public bool isAdmin(); // getter for property "admin"
public bool setAdmin(bool admin); // setter for property "admin"
```

It is not mandatory to use getters and setters. In all of these cases you can also go without the getter/setter and use **only** a **public** field:

```
public String name;
public String userName;
public bool admin;
```

Finally: it's also not required to have both getters and setters. If you have **only** a getter, Firebase will set the corresponding field directly. This *does* however require that your field name follows the naming conventions, so that Firebase can find the correct field to set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the your `noteRef` points to a document reference which is simillar to this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference noteRef = rootRef.collection("notes").document();
```

And the fields in your `Note` class are declared as:

```
private String title;
private String description;
```

When using this line of code: `Note note = new Note(title, description);`

Your database structure will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- notes (collection)
          |
          --- noteId (document) //Random document Id
               |
               --- title: "titleThatComesFromUserInput"
               |
               --- description: "descriptionThatComesFromUserInput"
```

The key properties of your document will be `title` and `description` (as the name of your fields in the `Note` class) and the corresponding values will be the exact text the user imputs in the `editTextTitle` and `editTextDescription` views in your activity.

Comment: Well this is what I thought, but actually the key names do not come from the member varialbe names, but from the getter method names (I found a confirmation in the mean time).

Comment: Please provide me an example. I'm not sure I understand you. Please add a database structure example.

Comment: Let's say my Pojo has the member varialbes `title` and `description` but I name the getter methods `getTitleXY` and `getDescriptionXY`, then the keys in the document will be named `titleXY` and `descriptionXY`

Comment: When the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects coming from the database, is looking for fields that follow the principles of the JavaBeans and are named accordingly to [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). So the corresponding getter for a field like `title` is `getTitle()` and not `getTitleXY()`. So never name the getter in another way than `getTitle()`. If you have fields in your database that are named according to those getters, to make it work entirely, delete old data and add fresh one.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?